# I want to know if my proofs about the supremum are correct.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $x \in \Bbb R$. Prove that $x = \sup\{q \in \Bbb Q: q \lt x\}$.

Proof 1:

Let $x \in \Bbb R$ and let $S=\{q \in \Bbb Q: q \lt x\}$.

Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there exists an $r \in  \Bbb Q$ such that: $$q \lt r \lt x$$

Since $x$ is an upper bound and $r \gt q$ with $r \in S$, $x$ must be the least upper bound.

---

Proof 2:

Let $x \in \Bbb R$ and let $S=\{q \in \Bbb Q: q \lt x\}$.

Suppose $y = \sup S$. We want to show that $y=x$.

Suppose $ y \gt x$. By the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, there exists an $r \in  \Bbb Q$ such that:$$x \lt r \lt y$$ 
We said $y$ is the least upper bound but $r \lt y$, which is a contradiction.

Suppose $y \lt x$. By the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, there exists an $r \in  \Bbb Q$ such that:$$y \lt r \lt x.$$

We said $y$ is the least upper bound, but $r \in S$, which is a contradiction to $y$ being the least upper bound.

$\therefore$ We must have that $y=x=\sup S$.

---

Are both these proofs correct? Which one is better/ more precise?

Comment: Nit pick.  But in proof 1 you never stated what $q$ was or that $q$ was an element of $\{q\in \mathbb Q|q < x\}$.

Comment: "x<r<y We said y is the least upper bound but r<y, which is a contradiction."  A contradiction of *what*?  Surely numbers less than a least upper bound exist.  So why can't $r < y$ exist?  Is it because $r \not \in \{q< x\}$.  That doesn't matter. Number less than an upper bound don't have to be in the set.

Comment: @fleablood well if r<y, surely y cannot be the least upperbound

Comment: Why not?  Is $r$ an upper bound?  You never made or justified any such claim.

Comment: My biggest worry is Do you actually know that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ at this time?  How did you define $\mathbb R$ and how did you prove $\mathbb Q$ was dense?

Comment: @fleablood, yes of course, $\Bbb R$ is a complete  ordered field because it satisfies those set of Axioms. And we proved that Q is dense in R in class.

Comment: @fleablood, well if $ r \gt x$, doesn't that imply thar $r$ is an upper bound?

Comment: "doesn't that imply thar r is an upper bound?"  Why?  Is $x$ an upper bound?  You never stated that either.  And if $x$ *is* an upper bound then $y > x$ is a contradiction without introducing $r$ at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Proof 1:
>
> Let x∈R and let S={q∈Q:q
>
> .
>
> Since Q is dense in R, there exists an r∈Q such that: q

What is $q$?  You need to state "Let $q\in S$".

> Since x
>   is an upper bound and r>q with r∈S, x
>
> must be the least upper bound.

Why?  This shows that $q$ is not an upper bound.  You must show that *no* number (whether or not is $S$) less than $x$ can be an upper bound.  You must show if $y < x$ then there is a rational $q$ so that $y < q < x$ and so $q \in S$ so $y$ can not be an upper bound.

But you have to show $x$ is an upper bound.

Actually you never stated that $x$ is an upper bound.  But it is. As for every $q \in S$, $q< x$.

Fix those two things and this is the better proof.  It's a straight definition.

> Proof 2:
>
> Suppose y=supS

How do you know $\sup S$ exists.  Is $S$ non-empty?  Is $S$ bounded above.  Both those must be shown.

> Suppose y>x . By the density of Q in R, there exists an r∈Q such that:
>   x
>
> , which is a contradiction.

A contradiction of what?  Real numbers less then $y$ exist.

Are you claiming that $r$ is an upper bound of $S$?  That would be a contradiction.  But why are you concluding $r$ is an upper bound of $S$?

(You can claim it as $r> x$ would imply for all $q \in S$ that $q < x < r$.)

> Suppose y
>
> We said y is the least upper bound, but r∈S, which is a contradiction
>   to y
>
> being the least upper bound.

That works but... Why introduce $y$ and then fit it to $x$.  Just work with finding $\sup S$ directly.

====

FWIW, my solution:

> $\mathbb Q$ is unbounded so for any $x\in \mathbb R$ there are $q < x$ so $S$ is not empty.  For any $q\in S$, $q < x$ so is an upper bound of $S$.  If $r< x$ then because $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ there exists a rational $q$ so that $r < q < x$.  So $q\in S$ and $r$ is not an upper bound so $x =\sup S$.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

The first proof doesn't make sense. You claim that $q<r<x$ without saying what $q$ is.

The second one is just fine.

Comment: q is some rational number in the set

Comment: You did not say that in the proof. And I don't see how did you deduce that $x$ must be the least upper bound.

Comment: "And I don't see how did you deduce that x must be the least upper bound. " Jose Carlos Santos is right.  You (the OP) had this backwards.  You showed that if $q\in S$ then $q$ is not an upper bound.  But you need to show that for *any* $w < x$ that $w$ is not an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

First one is both shorter and more clear -- an obvious winner to me.